# Meaning of "I'm deep in the mountains"

Tags: meaning

When someone says: "I'm deep in the mountains", does it mean that he is on a high mountain? because I don't think that going inside a mountain is possible.

Comment: Well, it is certainly possible to go inside a mountain. Bilbo and the rest of the Fellowship did it, famously. That said, in your example, what's meant is probably the same "deep" as "deep in the woods". The mountain range creates a 3D landscape, stretching away from civilization, and your friend is deep within that landscape, a good distance from where he started. Way in the back of the land, so to speak. For future questions, you may prefer to ask on our sister site, dedicated to helping people learn English as a foreign language: [ELL.se].

Comment: Notice that "mountains" is plural.

Comment: sense 6 https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deep

Answer (score 2):

Deep can mean "A long way inside" ([sense 6](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deep)). When you refer to "the mountains" (plural) you mean a mountainous region. Hence this means "A long way inside a mountainous region". It doesn't mean underground, nor does it necessarily mean on a mountain top. It does suggest you are far from civilisation.